# Are barium titanate ($\rm BaTiO_3$), magnesium titanium oxide ($\rm MgTiO_3$) transparent to near-infrared rays?

Tags: dielectric, infrared-radiation, optical-materials

Barium titanate (BaTiO3) and magnesium titanium oxide (MgTiO3) are commonly used dielectric materials in MLCCs. Are barium titanate (BaTiO3), magnesium titanium oxide (MgTiO3) transparent to near-infrared rays?